# Image sequence of .gif playing on WatchSimulator but not on AppleWatch

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am on **watchOS2 b4**.

I have a `WKInterfaceImage` named `animatedImage` which is connected properly and I am using

```
[self.animatedImage setImageNamed:@"image"];
[self.animatedImage startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 65) duration:6.0 repeatCount:0];
```

to animate several images. This works on the simulator but the images are not shown on the AppleWatch.

I have added a folder inside of my Watch-target that contains all the images. They are all named `image0.gif image1.gif` and so on.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed from .gif to .png it worked. I guess the simulator can handle .gif but the AppleWatch can´t.